# Mongodb insert & sort

Tags: node.js, mongodb, sorting, insert

Hi I am trying to insert and sort data at the same time but it is not working. Have someone experience with it?

My example code looks like this:

```
  collection.insert({id:"224535353", type:postValue, date:new Date},  {safe:true},{$sort: { id: -1 }}, function(err, result){
                        console.log(result);

    });
```

**Solution:**

The mistake was I tried to sort the same id's.

```
collection.find({id:req.session.loggedIn},{sort:{date:-1}}).toArray(function(err, posts) { 

            console.log(posts);
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You sort on find not on insert. Basically you don't want to care how the data is stored and it's mongodbs problem to retrieve it sorted if you want it sorted so insert with

```
  collection.insert({id:"224535353", type:postValue, date:new Date},                      
                       {safe:true},function(err, result){console.log(result);});
```

and later find sorted with

```
collection.find({}).sort({id:-1})
```

Comment: I will query and sort specified data. I have many objects with the same id. collection.find({id:req.session.loggedIn}).sort:({id:-1}).toArray(function(err, posts) { 
   
   console.log(posts);}

Comment: Yes but you query for a specfic id so assuming req.session.loggedIn is 5 then all documents returned by find will have id=5 so sorting them by id will change nothing in the result because they all have the same id.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure of what you're trying to achieve here or if you're using monk or but mongodb doesn't return a collection or even an array of docs when doing an insert. It just returns a writeResult, as you can see here.. http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/method/db.collection.insert/

What you CAN do is do the insert and then run a find query, like so...

```
collection.insert({id:"224535353", type:postValue, date:new Date},  {safe:true}, function(err, writeResult){
       collection.find({},{sort:{id:-1}}, function(e, result){
           console.log(result)
       })
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. I am using native MongoDB. I am using the find method in other position of my code. Inserting the data into mongodb is working but now I want to query the inserted datas sorted. I tried : collection.find({id:req.session.loggedIn},{sort:{id:-1}}).toArray(function(err, posts) {console.log(posts); } but its not working.

Comment: @machupichu why do you query for a specific id and then try to sort by it? All values of id find({id:req.session.loggedIn}) will be the same (i.e. req.session.loggedIn)

Comment: Hi the all values will be not the same. I query the raw which have the (req.session.loggedIn). I traverse the data and output it.

Comment: I think you're somehow confusing the use of `insert` with the use of `find`